# How can I assign names to some numbers to feed them into a random number generator as variables

Tags: python

I need some assistance here.

```
import urllib2
pen = urllib2.Request("http://silasanio.appspot.com/mean_stdev")
response = urllib2.urlopen(pen)
f = response.read()
print f


-0.0011935729005
0.0313498454115
...............
..............
```

the numbers above were returned together with some other texts.
My problem is I want those numbers as variables to feed a random number generator. That is I want the first number assigned mean and the second assigned standard_deviation. 
I need assistance on how to do that, please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can avoid making `f`, you can just use:

```
lines = response.readlines()
mean = float(lines[0])
stddev = float(lines[1])
```

If you need `f` for other purposes, replace the first of these statements with

```
lines = f.splitlines()
```